# Psensor, audible repeating sound for alert alarm?

Tags: lm-sensors, psensor

When using Psensor, is there a way to set an audible repeating sound for alert alarm? I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since psensor 0.8.0.4, open psensor preferences and set "Script executed when an alarm is raised" to the path of a shell script playing a sound.

Example of a trivial script which plays a sound:

```
#!/bin/sh

play -q /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav
```

You can upgrade psensor to a newer version than Ubuntu Trusty 11.04 (psensor 0.8.0.3) by using the PPA: ppa:jfi/ppa.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

Comment: The option is at the bottom of the sensors tab of the psensor preferences. It has been introduced since the 0.8.0.4 release.

Comment: You can upgrade it by using the PPA: ppa:jfi/ppa

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a newer version is going to be available in 14.10.